# Is there a size limit of 16k for Silverlight LocalSettings (IsolatedStorageSettings)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, isolatedstorage

I am trying to save my whole viewmodel into the IsolatedStorage Settings. It is quite large as it  contains many other VMs.

When I try and read the value it throws a "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream" error. This seems like a red-herring as I am not using files, I am using the IsolatedStorageSettings class.

I checked out the __LocalSettings file under my local app data directory and it appears to be truncated at 16k (halfway through an XML element name). I suspect it has a 16k limit and therefore on the next load the IsolatedStorage class sees it as an invalid file and throws a fit (it then blanks it back down to an empty file).

I would just like to confirm if there is a size limit of 16k on all your settings when using IsolatedStorageSettings?

Some ways around it is to serialize it as a file and rehydrate it instead of using Settings or to not use this approach at all (store less info). In anyone has a better idea please let me know?

Comment: Note that Debug.WriteLine is limited so the truncation might be coming from that. Split into an array by NewLine and writeline for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a lot more investigation and hair-pulling the 16k limit seems to be a red-herring. It may be relevant but the actual problem is a serialization issue.

There seems to be 2 issues here regarding the serialization of complex types to IsolatedStorageSettings. The first one is the one mentioned above where the _LocalSettings class is truncated at 16k halfway through an XML element. This causes the "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream" exception. The second is on a smaller complex type - after examining the contents of _LocalSettings it seems to write to it but then on the NEXT time you load up the app the first Settings.Save wipes all existing settings (ie. it does not load the existing ones and resave them). This makes the _LocalSettings reset to blank again (ie. ALL your settings are not persisted).

The problem was that one of my base types (incidentally the MVVM Light ViewModelBase - [read more about this here](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=231606)) does not have a public paramaterless constructor and is therefore not serializable (there was no warning on this, it just exhibited the strange behaviours above).

You have to exit the program to have this happen - when you read the setting after a write like this it works fine - I suspect Silverlight is doing more behind the scenes after you exit completely. If anyone can confirm this??

As soon as I made the base class serializable then it worked again.

Answer (score 2):

[`IsolatedStorageFile.IncreaseQuotaTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.increasequotato) is your friend.

Also review the various methods on the [`IsolatedStorageFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.aspx) class.

See examples [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/isolatedstorageinsilverlight07202009131242PM/isolatedstorageinsilverlight.aspx) (see "*Sample on how to modify the quota?*" section) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458794.aspx).

**Update**

In the other hand, maybe try to increase the size of the setting file by setting addresses to external files instead of embedding them in the setting itself, for example, if you have a big xml file, just set the setting to its address and handle the event of the settings file (I assume it's a subclass of [`ApplicationSettingsBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.aspx)).

Comment: Hmm - I don't think this is the problem. The _LocalSettings file is hitting 16k whereas the IS gets 1 meg by default (my class is maybe 100 k at a guess, it's just text info). I dumped out IsolatedStorageFile.AvailableFreeSpace and there is 1 meg free. I suspect that the IsolatedStorageSettings is functioning differently to reading/writing files to IS. I really need to know if LocalSettings are restricted to 16k as this is the size of the file where mine is truncated. Basically when I try and write a small setting it works but when I try and save the big setting it falls over at 16k.  Thanks